# How can I publish vector layers with Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geoserver

I am trying to publish my vector layers in geoserver as WFS using the Leaflet library and I get the error like in the picture. How can I fix this error and is there any other way to publish WFS with leaflet?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <head>
        <script src=" https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js "></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" ></script>
 
        <style>
            #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 600px; 
             box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
             
        var owsrootUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?';
 
        var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: 'webalani:il',
            outputFormat: 'application/json',
 
        };
        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
 
        var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
            
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            success: function (data) {
                var geojson = new L.geoJson(data, {
                    style: {"color":"#2ECCFA","weight":2},
                    }
                ).addTo(map);
            }
        });
               
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to run your leaflet file directly by double clicking on the file location on your disk. This will not work as the AJAX methods you are using require a web server to be used instead.

Make sure you are looking at `http://localhost....` not `file://.....` in your browser bar and all will be well.